# Send a notification on like or comment of modern Site pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, modern-pages, notifications

With current setting, author of modern site pages are getting notification on like or comment of the modern site page(SharePoint Online), but I want to send notification to another set of people or group in this case. Is it possible with power automate or any other OOB feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are the creator of the post, the email will be sent to you by default after someone leaves a comment. And the notification Email is only for the author of the page.

There is an open feedback pending in **feedbackportal.microsoft.com** (earlier UserVoice) to vote and put forward your suggestions.

https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/272f6297-dd1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8046

---

Is it possible with power automate ?

I am not able to find any relevant triggers from the list of SharePoint Triggers available in Power Automate.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/sharepoint-connector-actions-triggers

Comment: Thanks for the details Jefin!

Answer (score 0):

If you click the ⚙️ and navigate to Site Contents, the "Site Pages" (or go to: https://YOURTENANT.sharepoint.com/sites/YOURSITE/SitePages/Forms/ByAuthor.aspx).

The site library is just like a file library, so you can use the self-serve alerts on SharePoint. I'm not 100% sure if it'll work for likes and comments, but it would cover any changes to the page. [image: self-serve alerts on SharePoint]